# SQL0338N Error when putting together two functional queries

Tags: sql, db2

Thanks in advance for any help!

Using TOAD freeware and I put together 2 different functional queries with one as a table in the from statement with some criteria to join them together that is working fine in another query.  I am stumped why these two won't work together.

Error:

[image]

SQL Code with comments

```
--Runs without the BRAND table added 8 lines down fine
SELECT 'B2C6M6' AS COMBO, SITE
FROM (
  select site.ROWID_OBJECT AS SITE, l1.CHAIN_IND AS UP, NVL(NVL(NVL(NVL(SUBSTR(L5.PARTY_LVL,2,1),SUBSTR(L4.PARTY_LVL,2,1)),SUBSTR(L3.PARTY_LVL,2,1)),SUBSTR(L2.PARTY_LVL,2,1)),SUBSTR(L1.PARTY_LVL,2,1)) AS HIGH_DUMMY, COUNT(L1.ROWID_OBJECT)
  from C_PARTY as site, C_REL_PARTY as sb, C_PARTY as bca, C_PARTY as cg, C_REL_PARTY as cl, C_PARTY as l1,



------------VVV Runs on it's own fine VVV------------
    (SELECT TAB2.BRAND, TAB2.L1_UP, TAB2.L1
    FROM (
    (select L5.PARTY_NM3_CLS as BRAND, L5.ROWID_OBJECT as BRAND_NODE, L5.PARTY_LVL BRAND_LVL, L5.IS_DUMMY NODE_DUMMY, L1.ROWID_OBJECT as L1, L1.PARTY_NM1_CLS AS L1_NAME, L1.CHAIN_IND AS L1_UP, L1.IS_DUMMY AS L1_DUMMY
    FROM C_PARTY AS L5, C_REL_PARTY AS L54, C_PARTY AS L4, C_REL_PARTY AS L43, C_PARTY AS L3, 
    C_REL_PARTY AS L32, C_PARTY AS L2, C_REL_PARTY AS L21, C_PARTY AS L1
    WHERE L5.ROWID_OBJECT = L54.PARENT_ID AND L4.ROWID_OBJECT = L54.CHILD_ID AND L54.HUB_STATE_IND = '1' AND L54.DELETED_IND IS NULL
    AND L4.ROWID_OBJECT = L43.PARENT_ID AND L3.ROWID_OBJECT = L43.CHILD_ID AND L43.HUB_STATE_IND = '1' AND L43.DELETED_IND IS NULL
    AND L3.ROWID_OBJECT = L32.PARENT_ID AND L2.ROWID_OBJECT = L32.CHILD_ID AND L32.HUB_STATE_IND = '1' AND L32.DELETED_IND IS NULL
    AND L2.ROWID_OBJECT = L21.PARENT_ID AND L1.ROWID_OBJECT = L21.CHILD_ID AND L21.HUB_STATE_IND = '1' AND L21.DELETED_IND IS NULL
    AND L5.PARTY_NM3_CLS IS NOT NULL AND (L5.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '6' or L5.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Base Customer Node' OR L5.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '1' or L5.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Ultimate Parent')
    AND (L4.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '6' or L4.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Base Customer Node') AND (L3.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '6' or L3.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Base Customer Node')
    AND (L2.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '6' or L2.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Base Customer Node') AND (L1.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '6' or L1.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Base Customer Node')
    )UNION(
    select L4.PARTY_NM3_CLS as BRAND, L4.ROWID_OBJECT as BRAND_NODE, L4.PARTY_LVL BRAND_LVL, L4.IS_DUMMY NODE_DUMMY, L1.ROWID_OBJECT as L1, L1.PARTY_NM1_CLS AS L1_NAME, L1.CHAIN_IND AS L1_UP, L1.IS_DUMMY AS L1_DUMMY
    FROM C_PARTY AS L4, C_REL_PARTY AS L43, C_PARTY AS L3, C_REL_PARTY AS L32, C_PARTY AS L2, C_REL_PARTY AS L21, C_PARTY AS L1
    WHERE L4.ROWID_OBJECT = L43.PARENT_ID AND L3.ROWID_OBJECT = L43.CHILD_ID AND L43.HUB_STATE_IND = '1' AND L43.DELETED_IND IS NULL
    AND L3.ROWID_OBJECT = L32.PARENT_ID AND L2.ROWID_OBJECT = L32.CHILD_ID AND L32.HUB_STATE_IND = '1' AND L32.DELETED_IND IS NULL
    AND L2.ROWID_OBJECT = L21.PARENT_ID AND L1.ROWID_OBJECT = L21.CHILD_ID AND L21.HUB_STATE_IND = '1' AND L21.DELETED_IND IS NULL
    AND L4.PARTY_NM3_CLS IS NOT NULL AND (L4.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '6' or L4.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Base Customer Node' OR L4.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '1' or L4.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Ultimate Parent')
    AND (L3.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '6' or L3.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Base Customer Node') AND (L2.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '6' or L2.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Base Customer Node') 
    AND (L1.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '6' or L1.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Base Customer Node') AND L4.ROWID_OBJECT NOT IN (
      select L4.ROWID_OBJECT
      FROM C_PARTY AS L5, C_REL_PARTY AS L54, C_PARTY AS L4
      WHERE L5.ROWID_OBJECT = L54.PARENT_ID AND L4.ROWID_OBJECT = L54.CHILD_ID AND L54.HUB_STATE_IND = '1' AND L54.DELETED_IND IS NULL
      AND L5.PARTY_NM3_CLS IS NOT NULL AND (L5.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '6' or L5.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Base Customer Node' OR L5.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '1' 
      or L5.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Ultimate Parent') AND (L4.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '6' or L4.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Base Customer Node'))
    )UNION(
    select L3.PARTY_NM3_CLS as BRAND, L3.ROWID_OBJECT as BRAND_NODE, L3.PARTY_LVL BRAND_LVL, L3.IS_DUMMY NODE_DUMMY, L1.ROWID_OBJECT as L1, L1.PARTY_NM1_CLS AS L1_NAME, L1.CHAIN_IND AS L1_UP, L1.IS_DUMMY AS L1_DUMMY
    FROM C_PARTY AS L3, C_REL_PARTY AS L32, C_PARTY AS L2, C_REL_PARTY AS L21, C_PARTY AS L1
    WHERE L3.ROWID_OBJECT = L32.PARENT_ID AND L2.ROWID_OBJECT = L32.CHILD_ID AND L32.HUB_STATE_IND = '1' AND L32.DELETED_IND IS NULL
    AND L2.ROWID_OBJECT = L21.PARENT_ID AND L1.ROWID_OBJECT = L21.CHILD_ID AND L21.HUB_STATE_IND = '1' AND L21.DELETED_IND IS NULL
    AND L3.PARTY_NM3_CLS IS NOT NULL AND (L3.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '6' or L3.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Base Customer Node' OR L3.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '1' or L3.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Ultimate Parent')
    AND (L2.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '6' or L2.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Base Customer Node') AND (L1.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '6' or L1.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Base Customer Node') 
    AND L3.ROWID_OBJECT NOT IN (
      (select L3.ROWID_OBJECT
      FROM C_PARTY AS L5, C_REL_PARTY AS L54, C_PARTY AS L4, C_REL_PARTY AS L43, C_PARTY AS L3
      WHERE L5.ROWID_OBJECT = L54.PARENT_ID AND L4.ROWID_OBJECT = L54.CHILD_ID AND L54.HUB_STATE_IND = '1' AND L54.DELETED_IND IS NULL
      AND L4.ROWID_OBJECT = L43.PARENT_ID AND L3.ROWID_OBJECT = L43.CHILD_ID AND L43.HUB_STATE_IND = '1' AND L43.DELETED_IND IS NULL
      AND L5.PARTY_NM3_CLS IS NOT NULL AND (L5.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '6' or L5.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Base Customer Node' OR L5.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '1' or L5.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Ultimate Parent')
      AND (L4.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '6' or L4.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Base Customer Node') AND (L3.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '6' or L3.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Base Customer Node')
      )UNION(
      select L3.ROWID_OBJECT
      FROM C_PARTY AS L4, C_REL_PARTY AS L43, C_PARTY AS L3
      WHERE L4.ROWID_OBJECT = L43.PARENT_ID AND L3.ROWID_OBJECT = L43.CHILD_ID AND L43.HUB_STATE_IND = '1' AND L43.DELETED_IND IS NULL
      AND L4.PARTY_NM3_CLS IS NOT NULL AND (L4.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '6' or L4.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Base Customer Node' OR L4.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '1' 
      or L4.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Ultimate Parent') AND (L3.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '6' or L3.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Base Customer Node')))
    )UNION(
    select L2.PARTY_NM3_CLS as BRAND, L2.ROWID_OBJECT as BRAND_NODE, L2.PARTY_LVL BRAND_LVL, L2.IS_DUMMY NODE_DUMMY, L1.ROWID_OBJECT as L1, L1.PARTY_NM1_CLS AS L1_NAME, L1.CHAIN_IND AS L1_UP, L1.IS_DUMMY AS L1_DUMMY
    FROM C_PARTY AS L2, C_REL_PARTY AS L21, C_PARTY AS L1
    WHERE L2.ROWID_OBJECT = L21.PARENT_ID AND L1.ROWID_OBJECT = L21.CHILD_ID AND L21.HUB_STATE_IND = '1' AND L21.DELETED_IND IS NULL
    AND L2.PARTY_NM3_CLS IS NOT NULL AND (L2.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '6' or L2.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Base Customer Node') 
    AND (L1.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '6' or L1.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Base Customer Node') AND L2.ROWID_OBJECT NOT IN (
      (select L2.ROWID_OBJECT
      FROM C_PARTY AS L5, C_REL_PARTY AS L54, C_PARTY AS L4, C_REL_PARTY AS L43, C_PARTY AS L3, 
      C_REL_PARTY AS L32, C_PARTY AS L2, C_REL_PARTY AS L21, C_PARTY AS L1
      WHERE L5.ROWID_OBJECT = L54.PARENT_ID AND L4.ROWID_OBJECT = L54.CHILD_ID AND L54.HUB_STATE_IND = '1' AND L54.DELETED_IND IS NULL
      AND L4.ROWID_OBJECT = L43.PARENT_ID AND L3.ROWID_OBJECT = L43.CHILD_ID AND L43.HUB_STATE_IND = '1' AND L43.DELETED_IND IS NULL
      AND L3.ROWID_OBJECT = L32.PARENT_ID AND L2.ROWID_OBJECT = L32.CHILD_ID AND L32.HUB_STATE_IND = '1' AND L32.DELETED_IND IS NULL
      AND L2.ROWID_OBJECT = L21.PARENT_ID AND L1.ROWID_OBJECT = L21.CHILD_ID AND L21.HUB_STATE_IND = '1' AND L21.DELETED_IND IS NULL
      AND L5.PARTY_NM3_CLS IS NOT NULL AND (L5.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '6' or L5.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Base Customer Node' OR L5.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '1' or L5.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Ultimate Parent')
      AND (L4.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '6' or L4.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Base Customer Node') AND (L3.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '6' or L3.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Base Customer Node')
      AND (L2.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '6' or L2.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Base Customer Node') AND (L1.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '6' or L1.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Base Customer Node')
      )UNION(
      select L2.ROWID_OBJECT
      FROM C_PARTY AS L4, C_REL_PARTY AS L43, C_PARTY AS L3, C_REL_PARTY AS L32, C_PARTY AS L2
      WHERE L4.ROWID_OBJECT = L43.PARENT_ID AND L3.ROWID_OBJECT = L43.CHILD_ID AND L43.HUB_STATE_IND = '1' AND L43.DELETED_IND IS NULL
      AND L3.ROWID_OBJECT = L32.PARENT_ID AND L2.ROWID_OBJECT = L32.CHILD_ID AND L32.HUB_STATE_IND = '1' AND L32.DELETED_IND IS NULL
      AND L4.PARTY_NM3_CLS IS NOT NULL AND (L4.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '6' or L4.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Base Customer Node' OR L4.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '1' or L4.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Ultimate Parent')
      AND (L3.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '6' or L3.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Base Customer Node') AND (L2.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '6' or L2.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Base Customer Node') 
      )UNION(
      select L2.ROWID_OBJECT
      FROM C_PARTY AS L3, C_REL_PARTY AS L32, C_PARTY AS L2
      WHERE L3.ROWID_OBJECT = L32.PARENT_ID AND L2.ROWID_OBJECT = L32.CHILD_ID AND L32.HUB_STATE_IND = '1' AND L32.DELETED_IND IS NULL
      AND L3.PARTY_NM3_CLS IS NOT NULL AND (L3.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '6' or L3.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Base Customer Node' OR L3.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '1' 
      or L3.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Ultimate Parent') AND (L2.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '6' or L2.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Base Customer Node'))) 
    )UNION(
    select L1.PARTY_NM3_CLS as BRAND, L1.ROWID_OBJECT as BRAND_NODE, L1.PARTY_LVL BRAND_LVL, L1.IS_DUMMY NODE_DUMMY, L1.ROWID_OBJECT as L1, L1.PARTY_NM1_CLS AS L1_NAME, L1.CHAIN_IND AS L1_UP, L1.IS_DUMMY AS L1_DUMMY
    FROM C_PARTY AS L1
    WHERE L1.PARTY_NM3_CLS is not null and (L1.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '6' or L1.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Base Customer Node') AND L1.ROWID_OBJECT NOT IN (
      (select L1.ROWID_OBJECT
      FROM C_PARTY AS L5, C_REL_PARTY AS L54, C_PARTY AS L4, C_REL_PARTY AS L43, C_PARTY AS L3, 
      C_REL_PARTY AS L32, C_PARTY AS L2, C_REL_PARTY AS L21, C_PARTY AS L1
      WHERE L5.ROWID_OBJECT = L54.PARENT_ID AND L4.ROWID_OBJECT = L54.CHILD_ID AND L54.HUB_STATE_IND = '1' AND L54.DELETED_IND IS NULL
      AND L4.ROWID_OBJECT = L43.PARENT_ID AND L3.ROWID_OBJECT = L43.CHILD_ID AND L43.HUB_STATE_IND = '1' AND L43.DELETED_IND IS NULL
      AND L3.ROWID_OBJECT = L32.PARENT_ID AND L2.ROWID_OBJECT = L32.CHILD_ID AND L32.HUB_STATE_IND = '1' AND L32.DELETED_IND IS NULL
      AND L2.ROWID_OBJECT = L21.PARENT_ID AND L1.ROWID_OBJECT = L21.CHILD_ID AND L21.HUB_STATE_IND = '1' AND L21.DELETED_IND IS NULL
      AND L5.PARTY_NM3_CLS IS NOT NULL AND (L5.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '6' or L5.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Base Customer Node' OR L5.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '1' or L5.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Ultimate Parent')
      AND (L4.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '6' or L4.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Base Customer Node') AND (L3.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '6' or L3.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Base Customer Node')
      AND (L2.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '6' or L2.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Base Customer Node') AND (L1.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '6' or L1.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Base Customer Node')
      )UNION(
      select L1.ROWID_OBJECT
      FROM C_PARTY AS L4, C_REL_PARTY AS L43, C_PARTY AS L3, C_REL_PARTY AS L32, C_PARTY AS L2, C_REL_PARTY AS L21, C_PARTY AS L1
      WHERE L4.ROWID_OBJECT = L43.PARENT_ID AND L3.ROWID_OBJECT = L43.CHILD_ID AND L43.HUB_STATE_IND = '1' AND L43.DELETED_IND IS NULL
      AND L3.ROWID_OBJECT = L32.PARENT_ID AND L2.ROWID_OBJECT = L32.CHILD_ID AND L32.HUB_STATE_IND = '1' AND L32.DELETED_IND IS NULL
      AND L2.ROWID_OBJECT = L21.PARENT_ID AND L1.ROWID_OBJECT = L21.CHILD_ID AND L21.HUB_STATE_IND = '1' AND L21.DELETED_IND IS NULL
      AND L4.PARTY_NM3_CLS IS NOT NULL AND (L4.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '6' or L4.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Base Customer Node' OR L4.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '1' or L4.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Ultimate Parent')
      AND (L3.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '6' or L3.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Base Customer Node') AND (L2.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '6' or L2.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Base Customer Node') 
      AND (L1.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '6' or L1.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Base Customer Node')
      )UNION(
      select L1.ROWID_OBJECT
      FROM C_PARTY AS L3, C_REL_PARTY AS L32, C_PARTY AS L2, C_REL_PARTY AS L21, C_PARTY AS L1
      WHERE L3.ROWID_OBJECT = L32.PARENT_ID AND L2.ROWID_OBJECT = L32.CHILD_ID AND L32.HUB_STATE_IND = '1' AND L32.DELETED_IND IS NULL
      AND L2.ROWID_OBJECT = L21.PARENT_ID AND L1.ROWID_OBJECT = L21.CHILD_ID AND L21.HUB_STATE_IND = '1' AND L21.DELETED_IND IS NULL
      AND L3.PARTY_NM3_CLS IS NOT NULL AND (L3.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '6' or L3.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Base Customer Node' OR L3.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '1' or L3.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Ultimate Parent')
      AND (L2.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '6' or L2.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Base Customer Node') AND (L1.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '6' or L1.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Base Customer Node')
      )UNION(
      select L1.ROWID_OBJECT
      FROM C_PARTY AS L2, C_REL_PARTY AS L21, C_PARTY AS L1
      WHERE L2.ROWID_OBJECT = L21.PARENT_ID AND L1.ROWID_OBJECT = L21.CHILD_ID AND L21.HUB_STATE_IND = '1' AND L21.DELETED_IND IS NULL
      AND L2.PARTY_NM3_CLS IS NOT NULL AND (L2.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '6' or L2.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Base Customer Node') 
      AND (L1.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '6' or L1.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Base Customer Node'))
    ))) AS TAB2
    WHERE TAB2.BRAND_LVL = 'L1') as BRAND
------------^^^ Runs on it's own fine ^^^-----------



---------Rest of line 1 query that runs find---------
LEFT JOIN C_REL_PARTY L12 ON l1.ROWID_OBJECT = L12.CHILD_ID AND L12.DELETED_IND IS NULL AND L12.HUB_STATE_IND = '1'
LEFT JOIN C_PARTY L2 ON L12.PARENT_ID = L2.ROWID_OBJECT AND (L2.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '6' or L2.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Base Customer Node') AND L2.IS_DUMMY = 'Y'
LEFT JOIN C_REL_PARTY L23 ON L2.ROWID_OBJECT = L23.CHILD_ID AND L23.DELETED_IND IS NULL AND L23.HUB_STATE_IND = '1'
LEFT JOIN C_PARTY L3 ON L23.PARENT_ID = L3.ROWID_OBJECT AND (L3.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '6' or L3.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Base Customer Node' OR L3.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '1' or L3.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Ultimate Parent') AND L3.IS_DUMMY = 'Y'
LEFT JOIN C_REL_PARTY L34 ON L3.ROWID_OBJECT = L34.CHILD_ID AND L34.DELETED_IND IS NULL AND L34.HUB_STATE_IND = '1'
LEFT JOIN C_PARTY L4 ON L34.PARENT_ID = L4.ROWID_OBJECT AND (L4.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '6' or L4.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Base Customer Node' OR L4.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '1' or L4.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Ultimate Parent') AND L4.IS_DUMMY = 'Y'
LEFT JOIN C_REL_PARTY L45 ON L4.ROWID_OBJECT = L45.CHILD_ID AND L45.DELETED_IND IS NULL AND L45.HUB_STATE_IND = '1'
LEFT JOIN C_PARTY L5 ON L45.PARENT_ID = L5.ROWID_OBJECT AND (L5.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '6' or L5.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Base Customer Node' OR L5.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '1' or L5.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Ultimate Parent') AND L5.IS_DUMMY = 'Y'
where (site.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '4' or site.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Site') and (bca.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '20001' or bca.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Base Customer Account')
and (cg.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '7' or cg.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Customer Group') and (l1.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '6' or l1.BO_CLASS_CODE = 'Base Customer Node')
and site.ROWID_OBJECT = sb.PARENT_ID and bca.ROWID_OBJECT = sb.CHILD_ID
and l1.ROWID_OBJECT = cl.PARENT_ID and cg.ROWID_OBJECT = cl.CHILD_ID
and bca.SOURCE_ID = cg.SOURCE_ID and (
  ( bca.act_grp_type1 = cg.ACT_GRP_TYPE1 and bca.act_grp_field1 = cg.ACT_GRP_FIELD1 )
  or ( bca.act_grp_type2 = cg.ACT_GRP_TYPE1 and bca.act_grp_field2 = cg.ACT_GRP_FIELD1 )
  or ( bca.act_grp_type3 = cg.ACT_GRP_TYPE1 and bca.act_grp_field3 = cg.ACT_GRP_FIELD1 )
  or ( bca.act_grp_type4 = cg.ACT_GRP_TYPE1 and bca.act_grp_field4 = cg.ACT_GRP_FIELD1 )
  or ( bca.act_grp_type5 = cg.ACT_GRP_TYPE1 and bca.act_grp_field5 = cg.ACT_GRP_FIELD1 ))
and site.party_nm3_cls = brand.brand and l1.chain_ind = brand.l1_up and l1.rowid_object <> BRAND.L1
GROUP BY SITE.ROWID_OBJECT, l1.CHAIN_IND, NVL(NVL(NVL(NVL(SUBSTR(L5.PARTY_LVL,2,1),SUBSTR(L4.PARTY_LVL,2,1)),SUBSTR(L3.PARTY_LVL,2,1)),SUBSTR(L2.PARTY_LVL,2,1)),SUBSTR(L1.PARTY_LVL,2,1))
HAVING count(case when l1.IS_DUMMY = 'N' then 1 end) = 0 AND count(case when l1.IS_DUMMY = 'Y' then 1 end) > 1) AS TAB1
GROUP  BY SITE
HAVING COUNT(UP) = 1 AND COUNT(SITE) > 1
ORDER BY RAND()
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

I went through each of the ON statements a second time, but since they all exist without the extra query I don't see any issues with them.  Went through IBM's list of issues under my error and nothing else jumped out at me that I'm violating.  Sorry it's such a massive query to go through, thanks again!

Comment: My guess would be the `*  Column references in an ON clause must only reference columns of tables that are in the scope of the ON clause.` reason.

Comment: It does not look a very well written query. You might want to write it more cleanly, and your issue would probably then go away.

Comment: I wonder if the query would/could be better written using recursion

Comment: You could post the DDL.. see if we can recreate the error.  Of course it could be an bug in Db2 and if you could pass it by IBM Support if you really think it should run as-is

Comment: BTW Does it work if the middle bit is created as a view, and then that view is used in your SQL

Comment: I don't have the permissions to create a view, but I don't see why it wouldn't work; on a related note I don't believe my freeware let's me use a temp table.  I'm not familiar with recursion in SQL, I will read up on that thank you!

Answer (score 0):

My From table to be joined was not the one immediately prior to the join statement.

Rewrite:

FROM table, table, [added query as table], table
LEFT JOIN table on ....

Works fine